# Is there a name for X when X bitwise OR Y is Y?

Tags: terminology, bit-manipulation

I'm wondering if there is a mathematical or computer science term for a number X such that `Y | X = Y`? For example:

```
66536 | 1000 == 66536
```

In this case, 1000 is the "insert name here" of 66536. Perhaps there is no name for this..? I've tried searching for "bitwise OR returns itself" and other such terms but without luck so far.

Comment: For single bit variables $x,y$ we have $x\lor y=y$ iff $x\le y$. So perhaps "bitwise less-or-equal"?

Comment: I don't think there is one. Similarly to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element, I would call it "neutral element for $Y$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that $X$ is a subset of $Y$, in terms of bits set.